# Is there a built-in sortByKey() function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Say,$arr contains multiple sub-arrays with the key "pos",

```
$arr = sortByKey($arr,'pos');
```

After that the sub-array with smallest "pos" value will be ordered first,and so on.

**EDIT**

```
$sub1 = array('pos' => 2);
$sub2 = array('pos' => 1);
$arr = array($sub1,$sub2);
$arr = sortByKey($arr,'pos');
```

After this function,$arr will be array($sub2,$sub1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the ksort function.

here come the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) of the function.

sorry also I think you are ccase you are more looking into [uasort](http://ttp://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) you would be able to define a function to compare each of your elements and sort them

```
// Array to be sorted

print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, create_function('$a,$b', 'return $a[\'pos\'] == $b[\'pos\'] ? 0 : (($a[\'pos\'] < $b[\'pos\']) ? -1 : 1);'));
print_r($array);
```

have to be tested not sure about the double ? operator ...

Cheer

Comment: No,it order by the key,but I need it to order by the value with a specified key.

Comment: So it need 2 functions totally?

Comment: Sorry, I see you have added the proper answer now, but SO won't let me change -1 to +1. :-S

Answer (score 0):

Let me write you a function. Its not tested.

```
function subarray_sort($array, $subkey) {
  $sortarray=array();
  foreach($array as $item) {
      $sortarray[]=$item[$subkey];
  }

  array_multisort($sortarray, $array);
}
```